# Blow-up for ODE solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my ODE class we saw that if $f: I \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\varphi: J \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the maximal solution to the Cauchy problem
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = f(t, x)\\
x(t_0) = x_0,
\end{cases}
$\varphi$ may blow up. To be precise, we saw that if $\sup J < \sup I$, then
$$
\lim_{t \to \sup J}||\varphi(t) || = +\infty
$$
Is the converse also true?

Comment: What do you consider the "converse"? $e^t$ diverges to infinity, $\frac1{1-t}$ has a pole at a finite time, in both cases you could have $J=I$. ($\dot x=x$ or $\dot x=x^2$, $x(0)=1$ in both cases.)

Comment: @LutzLehmann by the converse I mean the implication $\lim_{t \to \sup J} ||\varphi(t)|| = +\infty \implies \sup J < \sup I$. The first example you provided answers my question. I don't really get the second one, though. How can the solution be defined on $J = I = \mathbb{R}$? Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You could artificially reduce to I=(-1,1)$, this falls still into the setup.